# Android url path pattern match

Tags: android

I am facing problem in matching urls having a particular word

```
android:scheme="http"
android:domain="example.com"
android:pathpattern="/.*-location-.*"
```

It should match urls for eg

"`http://example.com/bangalore-location-158`"

But fails for

"`http://example.com/all-bangalore-location-158`"

As after first '-' looks for 'l' and in failed ex, after first '-', it has 'b'

Pattern matcher fails safe if there is first mismatch. But actually failed ex has "-location-" actually

So looking for pattern matcher, which looks for -location- completely.

Comment: have a look here if it may help you -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762251/android-matching-a-url-pattern